# How to configure a prometheus target for kubelet metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I would like to plot in Grafana, the metrics for the readiness/liveness probes for some of my pods. Currently, the way I am deploying prometheus in my cluster is using:

`helm install prometheus stable/prometheus -n prometheus`

I am able to see all standard metrics by going to the prometheus UI, but I am trying to figure out how to get the probes metrics. Apparently the kubelet expose these metrics in [/metrics/probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/monitoring/), but I don't know how to configure them. Moreover, I noted that apparently the "standard" metrics are grabbed from the kubernetes api-server on the /metrics/ path, but so far I haven't configured any path nor any config file (I just run the above command to install prometheus). I am assuming that this /metrics/ path is hardcoded somewhere in the helm chart repo, but since I want to get the metrics for the kubelets, this might be trickier, as my understanding is that he api-server lives in the master k8s node, and the kubelet only runs on the worker nodes (so I have no idea where to point the /metrics/probes path).

Answer (score 3):

Use [Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) and create [ServiceMonitor](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#prometheusioscrape) in which you can specify the endpoints, ports exposed by kubelet or any other component. Prometheus will start scraping the endpoints for metrics.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: kubelet
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubelet
spec:
  jobLabel: k8s-app
  endpoints:
  - port: https-metrics
    scheme: https
    interval: 30s
    tlsConfig:
      insecureSkipVerify: true
    bearerTokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  - port: https-metrics
    scheme: https
    path: /metrics/cadvisor
    interval: 30s
    honorLabels: true
    tlsConfig:
      insecureSkipVerify: true
    bearerTokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kubelet
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - kube-system
```